# Scatter Plots for graphs from codes

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, ide

Kindly assist with the applying the code. I am trying to use it on an online application for Python and it is not working.

For Model 1 (study hours as the independent variable), the scatter plot would have study hours on the x-axis and exam score on the y-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

study_hours = [4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 8]
exam_score = [85, 90, 80, 95, 70, 100]

plt.scatter(study_hours, exam_score)

plt.xlabel('Study Hours')
plt.ylabel('Exam Score')
plt.title('Model 1: Study Hours vs Exam Score')

plt.show()
```

For Model 2 (study hours and sleep hours as independent variables), we can create a 3D scatter plot with study hours and sleep hours on the x and y axes, and exam score on the z-axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

study_hours = [4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 8]
sleep_hours = [7, 6, 5, 8, 6, 9]
exam_score = [85, 90, 80, 95, 70, 100]

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(study_hours, sleep_hours, exam_score)

ax.set_xlabel('Study Hours')
ax.set_ylabel('Sleep Hours')
ax.set_zlabel('Exam Score')
ax.set_title('Model 2: Study Hours and Sleep Hours vs Exam Score')

plt.show()
```

I have use different online ide Python application and it is not executing.

Comment: I've just tested this locally, and the code is executing and it's showing the graphs. Have you installed matplotlib? Edit - actually you may not need to install anything depending on the online side you are using. I've also tried it on https://www.codabrainy.com/en/python-compiler/ and it works out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. I would admit that the suggested compiler works for.  I am a starter and I am open to your advice also. Thank you.